# Table Filter with Stackable.js - (How to copy <tr> data-attributes?)

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm using [stackable.js](https://github.com/johnpolacek/stacktable.js/) for a responsive table. This works great at generating a mobile friendly table (however) I'm also trying to incorporate a table filter that requires data attribute's to work. Unfortunately these data attributes do not copy over to the mobile version of the table so I need to figure out how to amend the script to include them.

---

*I managed to work out something using jQuery `.data()` and a for loop.*

```
var data = $(this).data(),
    tr_data = [];

for(key in data) {
    tr_data.push("data-"+key + "=" + data[key]);
}
```

This cycles through the `<tr>` to gather all attribute pairs and push them to an array. However, when adding the array to the markup the appended attributes are not correctly formatted.

***They copy into the mobile table < tr > but the quotes are in the wrong place and the comma's need to be removed - (see below).***

```
data-tags="Tag" 2,data-priority="Urgent,data-milestone=Milestone" 2,data-status="In" progress,data-assigneduser="Larry,data-taskId=1"
```

---

***The attributes "should" match the desktop < tr > formatting - (see below).***

```
data-task-id="1" data-assigned-user="Larry" data-status="In Progress" data-milestone="Milestone 2" data-priority="Urgent" data-tags="Tag 2"
```

---

***CodePen here:*** [https://codepen.io/jinch/pen/JjJbzww?editors=0010](https://codepen.io/jinch/pen/JjJbzww)

– *Line #125 is where the array is created.*

– *Line #135, #142, #145 ~ is where the "tr_data" variable array is added to the markup.*

*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out the formatting issue by adding quotes around the attribute value `"'"+data[key]+"'"`. Also used join method `'+tr_data.join(" ") +'` to remove the commas.

```
var data = $(this).data(),
    tr_data = [];

    for(key in data) {
      tr_data.push("data-"+key + "=" + "'"+data[key]+"'");
 }
```

And this is one example how I added the array to the markup:

```
bodyMarkup += '<tr class="' + tr_class +'" '+tr_data.join(" ") +'>';
```

---

**If in need of a table filter using stackable.js ~ here is a
working CodePen:** https://codepen.io/jinch/pen/JjJbzww?editors=0010